# Beautifulsoup time differences

Tags: python, web-scraping, time, beautifulsoup

I am webscraping urls on a certain site with grequests and beautifulsoup4. The runtime of the program is 25 seconds. When I tried to look for the cause of it I have found it odd, that this foor loop has two different outcomes in time.

```
import time
import bs4 as bs
import grequests


rs = (grequests.post(u, data = payload) for u in urls)
requests = grequests.imap(rs)

t1 = time.perf_counter()

infoPages = []
for response in requests:
    t3 = time.perf_counter()
    infoPages.append(bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml'))
    t4 = time.perf_counter()
    print(t4-t3)

t2 = time.perf_counter()
print(t2-t1)
```

The output is the following:

```
0.07943480000000003
0.07001459999999993
0.075399
0.07141719999999996
0.07378570000000018
0.06506450000000008
0.0753301000000004
0.054058200000000056
0.06016950000000065
0.0716176000000015
0.04789030000000061
0.07726519999999937
0.06198320000000024
0.05211830000000006
0.04859970000000047
0.10367259999999945
0.08496710000000007
0.045592300000002695
0.0656680999999999
0.056729100000001864
0.10122460000000189
0.05465159999999969
0.13292039999999972
0.06879819999999981
0.07439620000000247
24.9492973
```

Why the sum of the individual times is 1.7727681 instead of 24.9492973?

Comment: I'm not familiar with grequests. But if it's making the request at the start of each iteration, it's not being included in your loop. Your loop is only accounting for the the time it takes to append the beautifulsoup object.

Comment: @chitown88 I think you are right. I tought that the request is being callded in the line: rs = (grequests.post(u, data = payload) for u in urls). But measuring the iteration independently showd me that it takes more time.